# I can't loop through a directory which has images

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried to loop through a directory which has images inside. There are 45 images inside that directory but when I executed the file the program gave me only one image and then it stopped the loop immediately. I don't know what I did wrong with it and also I have tried both for loops, one within the comment and another one is outside the command.

my code

```
import cv2
import argparse
import os
from imutils import paths

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to not hong dataset")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="path to output directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

haar_cascade = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_cascade)

print("\n[INFO] Working on image...")

"""
for imagePath in sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))):
    i = 0
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    #image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, 
                                    minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        sub_face = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        p = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(str(i).zfill(5))])
        sub_face = cv2.resize(sub_face, (64, 64))
        #sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite(p, sub_face)
    i += 1
"""

for imagePath in os.listdir(args["dataset"]):
    i = 0
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, 
                                    minSize=(30, 30))

    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        sub_face = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        p = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(str(i).zfill(5))])
        sub_face = cv2.resize(sub_face, (64, 64))
        #sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite(p, sub_face)
    i += 1
```

Comment: How many files does os.listdir(args["dataset"] return?

Comment: both `os.listdir(args["dataset"])` and `sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))` return only one file

Comment: Since you're parsing arguments, what exactly do you pass in? Directory with the images, right?

Comment: yes the directory with the images sir

Comment: `ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to not hong dataset")` The path is given as the second argument, right?

Comment: It is the first argument and the --output is the second argument

Comment: `python notHong_crop.py --dataset not_hong/not_hong_faces --output after_crop/not_hong_face` like this

Comment: What does args['dataset'] return?

Comment: It returns a path to the directory where it has images inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215064/discussion-between-zenalc-and-hong-zz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commented out code works fine. Just move the i = 0 statement outside the loop (since it reassigns it to 0 each time), and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You keep setting `i = 0` in your loop and thus keep overwriting the output file. instead do

```
for i, imagePath in enumerate(os.listdir(args["dataset"])):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, 
                                    minSize=(30, 30))

    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        sub_face = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        p = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(str(i).zfill(5))])
        sub_face = cv2.resize(sub_face, (64, 64))
        #sub_face = cv2.cvtColor(sub_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite(p, sub_face)
```

A general way to debug this kind of thing is to put a few prints in the code. For instance `print("input", imagePath)` at the top and `print("output", p)` near the bottom would have shown the problem.

Comment: OP states that os.listdir(args["dataset"]) only returns one file. So, isn't there also an issue with that, and not just the variable i?

Comment: I did what you told me to do and when I execute the file I got `input 0001.jpg` like that but nothing save into the directory.